# Same genesis for private network?

Tags: private-blockchain

I have initialized one private node using geth and Genesis file, and now I want to span another node, in genesis file, I have mentioned on the account which will be pre-funded now I want Ans of below questions

- If I use the same genesis file to span another node what will happen as I mentioned one account to be pre-funded, can someone change it and have their account pre-funded?
- As I came to know the same genesis file is required if you want to build your own private network to set up another node is there any way I don't have share Genesis.json to setting up other nodes?

Comment: And is there any way I can restrict others to have there account pre-funded white building private network?

Answer (score 0):

Modifications to the genesis file will generate a different genesis block. And blockchains with different genesis block cannot synchronize.

If someone modifies your genesis file they are creating a new blockchain that is separate from the one you are running.

Comment: Ok, it's mean if I created Genesis.json and pre-funded my account then if someone tries to change my genesis.json and try to sync it won't happen and in a way, it's preventing other to pre-fund their account as for that they need to change the Genesis.json

Comment: Also, I created my own private blockchain and pre-funded my account with some ETH, now I want these ETH to be integrated with Exchange for Trading with a different name is it possible?

Comment: Once a blockchain is created and it is running you cannot add new accounts to the genesis file. For the exchange it is better to search for existing questions about it. I think it was asked previously.